# ggplot2 geom_tile: how to have no spacing between lines when plotting non-continuous data

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to do a levelplot using ggplot2 for a (meteorological) variable. The variable is measured continuously in time (my x-axis), but in non-continuous heights (y-axis) at every time step.
The produced plot therefore shows data at the heights (y-coordinates) specified, but nothing in between.
Here's an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- runif(400, min=0, max=10)
index <- c(1:20)
heights <- c(1,2,3,4,5,7,9,12,15,19,23,28,33,39,45,52,59,67,75,83)
dat <-     as.data.frame(cbind(expand.grid(X=index,Y=heights),data))                        
ggplot(dat, aes(x=dat[,1], y=dat[,2],z=dat[,3])) +geom_tile(aes(fill=dat[,3]))
```

This produces the following plot:
[image: image here]

Is there an easy way to fill the plot fully, i.e. make the lines in the upper part of the plot broader?
Thank you!

Comment: `geom_tile` takes a `height` aesthetic that you can use. I would advise to not use `dat[,1]` to refer to data using `ggplot`, use variable names instead.

Comment: I would suggest looking at this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48580629/1286528) about extrapolating missing values when plotting something similar

Comment: @Axeman, could you please elaborate about the height argument? I assume it would be some kind of vector specifying heights for every line in the plot?

Comment: @PoGibas, thank you for that link. I was trying to avoid having to interpolate my data for laziness reasons, but it might be the way I have to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK one more solution.. you could interpolate using the `approx` function. Although maybe 2D kriging would be more appropriate for your application???

```
library(purrr)
dat2<- dat %>%
  split(.$X) %>%
  map_dfr(~ approx(.$Y, .$data, xout =1:83), .id = "X") 

ggplot(dat2, aes(x=as.integer(dat2$X), y=dat2$x, z=dat2$y)) +geom_tile(aes(fill=dat2$y))
```

That will give you :
[image]

Comment: Just tested this on my data, it works and it looks good. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the height and width attributes in `geom_tile`, alternatively `geom_rect`

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- runif(400, min=0, max=10)
index <- c(1:20)
heights <- c(1,2,3,4,5,7,9,12,15,19,23,28,33,39,45,52,59,67,75,83)

dat <- crossing(index = index, heights = heights) %>% 
  mutate(
    Z = data,
    index0 = index - 1) %>% 
  left_join(data_frame(heights, heights0 = c(0, heights[-length(heights)])))    

ggplot(dat, aes(xmin = index0, xmax = index, ymin = heights0, ymax = heights, fill = Z)) +
  geom_rect()
```

This assumes that your heights are the top of each level and that they start at zero.

[image]

Comment: I like this one, but alas, the height information I have in my real data marks the center of the grid points.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the y axis to be `factor` in order to eliminate the dead space. This will, however, not make the upper lines broader.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=dat[,1], y=factor(dat[,2]),z=dat[,3])) +geom_tile(aes(fill=dat[,3]))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I would really like to retain the spatial information that I have in my heights.

Comment: Then, I think you need to fill the empty lines with the upper or lower information. I am working on that. brb with an edit